# Insert quotes at start and end of string array

Tags: powershell

I have an array of IP addresses, sample array below:

```
$arr = "22.22.22.22", "33.33.33.33", "44.44.44.44"
```

I am trying to insert quotes `"` at the start & end of each IP and convert the array to a string value. I have tried:

```
$arr | ForEach-Object { $newArr += $_.Insert(0,'" ') }
```

Output:

```
$newArr
" 22.22.22.22" 33.33.33.33" 44.44.44.44
```

Desired string output:

```
"22.22.22.22" "33.33.33.33" "44.44.44.44"
```

Is this possible using powershell?

Comment: Do you want to see the double quotes and the space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one idea. First, convert the array to a string with the `" "` separator, then prepend and append the `"` character.

```
$newStr = '"' + [system.String]::Join('" "',$arr) + '"'
# "22.22.22.22" "33.33.33.33" "44.44.44.44"
```

Answer (score 2):

Or make use of the `-f` Format operator.

Something like

```
($arr | ForEach-Object { '"{0}"' -f $_ }) -join ' '
```

or shorter:

```
'"{0}"' -f ($arr -join '" "')
```